# Syntax in R for prediction

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

How do I perform this loop in RStudio using R library? Actually my dataset has over 100,000 rows and need some efficient syntax that can produce something similar to this for loop

## Use previous row's value to predict for next all rows(in col d) after rows when data not available

```
# df is a dataframe with columns b,c,d,p.
        
    
    d = c(1, 2, 4, NA, NA)
    b = c(1,1,1,2,2) 
    c=c(1,1,1,1,1)
    
    df= data.frame(cbind(b,c,d))
    df$p <- c(0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.3)
    
    for(i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)) {
      if (df$b[i + 1] > df$c[i + 1]) {
        df$d[i + 1] = df$d[i] * (1 - df$p[i + 1])
      } else{
        df$d[i + 1] = df$d[i+1]
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you are looping for `i` in `1:nrow(df)`, when the loop counter reaches the upper limit `i + 1` doesn't exist. Also, the question has nothing to do with `tidyverse`, don't load the package.

Answer (score 0):

This vectorized code gives the same output as the question's `for` loop. And is much faster.

```
inx <- seq_along(df$a)[-1]
b_greater <- df$b[inx] > df$c[inx]
df$a[inx] <- df$d[inx - 1]
df$a[inx][b_greater] <- df$d[inx - 1][b_greater] * (1 - df$p[inx][b_greater])

df
#  b c  d   a   p
#1 1 1  1  NA 0.1
#2 1 1  2 1.0 0.2
#3 1 1  4 2.0 0.1
#4 2 1 NA 3.6 0.1
#5 2 1 NA  NA 0.3
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be giving the right output on the dataset I am working on

Comment: @YatinGupta Can you post a data set that can reproduce the error?